# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I just have one quick question about what seems to have been a limitation with ASP.NET Web API Attribute Routing, but hoping I just suck at research. In my controller, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{apiRoot}/customers/{id:int}/orders")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int id) {...}
}
```

Where `{apiRoot}` is defined in either a configuration file.

This may not actually be necessary, but I'd like to know how to put a specific path in the route attribute without having to code a static path. Is the general idea here supposed to be that you only put text into the route path, except for your parameters which go in `{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about switching to using a RoutePrefix:

```
[MyRoutePrefix]
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("customers/{id:int}/orders")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int id) {...}
}

public class MyRoutePrefixAttribute : RoutePrefixAttribute
{
    public MyRoutePrefixAttribute() 
    {
        Prefix = "the route prefix";
    }
}
```

RoutePrefixAttribute isn't sealed like RouteAttribute so extending it should allow you do what you need. Assuming, of course, that all of the controllers in a single class using the same root path.

Note: I haven't had a chance to try this but given what I know of attribute routing, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Turns out that just using the RoutePrefix attribute by itself works great. I didn't want to have to inherit RoutePrefix, but just decorating the class with the attribute and path works great. I could have probably fixed it via inheritance, but just using RoutePrefix works fine.

Thanks for the answer!